# data size bigger than 1 has rendering issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rendering, react-native-flatlist

data that worked looks like this
(I used JSON.stringify function to see how the data looks like)
[{"_id":"612e60c4ce136a1f4454c938", "individualPurchasePrice":9800,"teamPurchasePrice":640, "eventDealCategory":"DysonHairDryer"}]

below is the data that didn't work
[{"_id":"612e60c4ce136a1f4454c938", "individualPurchasePrice":9800,"teamPurchasePrice":640, "eventDealCategory":"JMWHairDryer"}, {"_id":"612e60c4ce136a1f4454c938", "individualPurchasePrice":9800,"teamPurchasePrice":640, "eventDealCategory":"JMWHairDryer"},]

this is the error message

Element type is invalid:expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

```
import React from 'react'
    import { SafeAreaView, View, Dimensions, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
    import ItemStore from '../stores/ItemStore'
    import ImageManager from '../images/ImageManager'
    import ItemListWithoutCategory from '../components/item/ItemListWithoutCategory'
    import TimeDealItemComponent from '../components/item/TimeDealItemComponent'
    
const dims = Dimensions.get('window')

const TimeDealItemScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const { eventDealCategoryName } = route.params
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ScrollView style={{ height: 40, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
        <ImageManager
          source='TimeDealGradientImage'
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
          }}
        />
        <ItemListWithoutCategory
          isFrom='TimeDealItemScreen'
          ItemSeparatorComponent={<View style={{ height: 16 }} />}
           ListFooterComponent={
            <>
              <View style={{ height: 16, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} />
            </>
          }
          data={ItemStore?.eventDealItems?.filter(
            (item) => item.eventDealCategory === eventDealCategory,
          )}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 8 }}>
              <TimeDealItemComponent item={item} index={index} />
            </View>
          )}
          ListFooterComponent={
            <>
              <View style={{ height: 16, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} />
            </>
          }
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default TimeDealItemScreen
```

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
import { FlatList } from 'react-native'
import ItemStore from '../../stores/ItemStore'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite'
import UserStore from '../../stores/UserStore'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import viewabilityConfig from '../config/viewabilityConfig'

const ItemListWithoutCategory = observer(
  ({
    ListEmptyComponent,
    ListFooterComponent,
    ItemSeparatorComponent,
    data,
    renderItem,
    ListHeaderComponent,
    isFrom,
    ref,
    onEndReached,
    numColumns,
  }) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    const onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback(
      ({ viewableItems, changed }) => {
        changed.forEach((item) => {
          if (item.isViewable) {
            const addedImpressionItems = {
              itemId: item.item?._id,
              itemTitle: item.item?.itemTitle,
              loggedAt: new Date(),
              isFrom,
            }
            ItemStore.addImpressionItems(addedImpressionItems)
          }
        })
      },
      [ItemStore.screenOnFocusMyOrder],
    )
    const viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs = useRef([
      { viewabilityConfig, onViewableItemsChanged },
    ])
    return (
      <FlatList
        ref={ref}
        viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs={viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs.current}
        data={data}
        ListHeaderComponent={ListHeaderComponent}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item?._id + index.toString()}
        ListEmptyComponent={ListEmptyComponent}
        ListFooterComponent={ListFooterComponent}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparatorComponent}
        onEndReached={onEndReached}
        numColumns={numColumns}
      />
    )
  },
)

export default ItemListWithoutCategory
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import BlackText from '../texts/BlackText'
import GrayText from '../texts/GrayText'
import BasicButton from '../buttons/BasicButton'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite'
import UserStore from '../../stores/UserStore'
import OrderStore from '../../stores/OrderStore'
import ImageManager from '../../images/ImageManager'
import backendApis from '../../utils/backendApis'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import ItemStore from '../../stores/ItemStore'
import RedText from '../texts/RedText'
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image'
import ImageTextTimer from '../texts/ImageTextTimer'
import commaNumber from 'comma-number'

const dims = Dimensions.get('window')

const TimeDealItemComponent = observer(({ item, index }) => {
  const FULL_GAGE_WIDTH = 70
  const CURRENT_GAGE_WIDTH = item.stockSoldPercentage
  const GAGE_HEIGHT = 16
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const TRANSPARENT_GRAY_CIRCLE_SIZE = 80
  const [eventDealStatusHere, setEventDealStatusHere] = useState(0)
  const [orderRecord, setOrderRecord] = useState('unpurchased')

  useEffect(() => {
    const eventStartedDate = new Date(item.eventDealStartedAt) // x
    const now = new Date().getTime() // y
    const oneDayTerm = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1 // 7일
    const stockleft = item.eventDealStock - item.totalOrderQuantity

    if (eventStartedDate > new Date(now)) {
      setEventDealStatusHere('preOpened')
    } else if (
      eventStartedDate < new Date(now) &&
      eventStartedDate > new Date(now - oneDayTerm) &&
      stockleft > 0
    ) {
      setEventDealStatusHere('opened')
    } else if (
      eventStartedDate < new Date(now) &&
      eventStartedDate > new Date(now - oneDayTerm) &&
      stockleft <= 0
    ) {
      setEventDealStatusHere('temporarilyClosed')
    } else setEventDealStatusHere('closed')
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      OrderStore.loadedUserOrdersList.find(
        (order) =>
          [
            'pre-shipping',
            'shipping',
            'exchanging',
            'arrived',
            'reviewed',
          ].includes(order.status) && item._id === order.itemInfo.itemId,
      )
    ) {
      setOrderRecord('purchased')
    } else {
      setOrderRecord('unpurchased')
    }
  }, [OrderStore.loadedUserOrdersList])

  const StockInfoTextComponent = ({ text }) => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignContent: 'center',
          // backgroundColor: 'grey',
        }}
      >
        <GrayText text={text} fontSize={14} dark numberOfLines={1} />
      </View>
    )
  }
  const StockInfoText = () => {
    if (eventDealStatusHere === 'preOpened') {
      return (
        <StockInfoTextComponent
          text={`${commaNumber(item.eventDealStock)}개 입고 예정`}
        />
      )
    }
    if (eventDealStatusHere === 'temporarilyClosed') {
      return <StockInfoTextComponent text='일시적 물량 소진' />
    }
    if (eventDealStatusHere === 'closed') {
      return <StockInfoTextComponent text='재고 전량 소진' />
    }
    return <></>
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: '100%',
        }}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            marginTop: 12,
            padding: 8,
            borderRadius: 8,
          }}
          activeOpacity={1.0}
          onPress={() => {
            if (ItemStore.isLoadingItemScreen) {
              return
            }
            ItemStore.setIsLoadingItemScreen(true)
            navigation.push('MainStackDItemScreen', {
              itemId: item._id,
              itemInfo: item.itemInfo,
              enteringComponent: 'TimeDealItemComponent',
            })
            setTimeout(() => {
              ItemStore.setIsLoadingItemScreen(false)
            }, 1000)
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              marginTop: 4,
              borderRadius: 4,
            }}
          >
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 2,
                flexDirection: 'column',
                paddingHorizontal: 8,
              }}
            >
              <View
                style={{
                  paddingBottom: 8,
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  paddingRight: 16,
                }}
              >
                <BlackText
                  text={item.itemTitle}
                  fontSize={16}
                  numberOfLines={2}
                />
              </View>
              {/* 1.아이템타이틀 끝 */}
              {/* 7. 게이지 시작 */}
              <View
                style={{
                  alignContent: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                }}
              >
                {eventDealStatusHere === 'opened' && (
                  <View
                    style={{
                      flexDirection: 'row',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                  >
                    <View
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor: '#E89FA1',
                        height: GAGE_HEIGHT,
                        width: FULL_GAGE_WIDTH,
                        borderRadius: 12,
                      }}
                    >
                      <View
                        style={{
                          backgroundColor: '#EC4F48',
                          height: GAGE_HEIGHT,
                          width: FULL_GAGE_WIDTH * CURRENT_GAGE_WIDTH,
                          borderRadius: 12,
                        }}
                      />
                    </View>
                    {/* opened */}
                    {eventDealStatusHere === 'opened' && (
                      <View
                        style={{
                          flexDirection: 'row',
                          alignContent: 'center',
                          paddingLeft: 8,
                          // backgroundColor: 'grey',
                        }}
                      >
                        <GrayText
                          text={item.stockLeft}
                          fontSize={12}
                          numberOfLines={1}
                        />
                        <GrayText
                          text='개 남음'
                          fontSize={12}
                          numberOfLines={1}
                        />
                      </View>
                    )}
                  </View>
                )}
              </View>
              {/* 7. 게이지 끝 */}
      

          {orderRecord === 'purchased' && (
            <View
              style={{
                borderRadius: 4,
                paddingTop: 10,
              }}
            >
              <>
                <BasicButton
                  width={30}
                  text='이미 구매하신 아이템입니다.'
                  eventDealClosed
                  backgroundColor='#B3B4B7'
                />
              </>
            </View>
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
})

export default TimeDealItemComponent
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve and the current unexpected result you're getting?

Comment: I want to render data successfully and show item lists on screen,

Comment: but it only works when the data size is 1 (when the data size is bigger than 1, error message shows up )

Comment: Which the error you're getting?

Comment: Error message like this shows up on the screen. >>  Element type is invalid:expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: Can you edit  answer with code implementation for `<TimeDealItemComponent item={item} index={index} />` and `<ItemListWithoutCategory/>` components. It seems that those components built on top of FlatList

Comment: I uploaded both codes! Thanks a lot.

Comment: The data you provided are not ehat consumed by `TimeDealItemComponent`

Answer (score 0):

```
below is the data that didn't work 

[{"_id":"612e60c4ce136a1f4454c938", "eventDealCategory":"JMWHairDryer"}, {"_id":"612e60c4ce136a1f4454c938", "eventDealCategory":"JMWHairDryer"},]
```

It does not work in second example because instead of one object you have array of objects. To render them you need to map throught array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have one more question. I added third line to see map function works but it still shows same error message. (.map((item)=>item)

Comment: data={ItemStore?.eventDealItems
          ?.filter((item) => item.eventDealCategory === 'CharmZoneMask')
          .map((item) => item)}

Comment: Can you correct this code `<GrayTex text={item.stockLeft} fontSize={12} numberOfLines={1} />`. `item.stockLeft` is not property of `item`